# React not outputting axios catch errors on bad API call, getting JavaScript errors instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When I make a bad request to my API that should not return anything, it crashes my app but doesn't console.log any of the error messages I set up for axios, instead I get a bunch of errors regarding the map I used in one of my components. I cannot seem to find the cause of the error.

The component with the map:

```
const Viewer=({poem})=>{
    return(
        <>
        {
            poem.map((item) => {
                let author = item.author
                let title = item.title
                let lines = item.lines
                if (author!= undefined && title!= undefined) {
                    return(
                        <>
                        <div className="viewer">
                            <div className="author">{author}</div>
                            <div className="title">{title}</div>
                            <div className="lines">
                                {lines.map((line) =>
                                    <div>{line}</div>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        </>
                    )
                }
            })
        }
        </>
    )
}
```

Afterwards my page goes blank until I reload it and I get 3 error messages saying that poem.map is not a function.

Here is how I am fetching the API:

```
const searchPoem= (event) => {
    if(event.key==="Enter")
    {
      axios.get("https://poetrydb.org/"+option+"/"+search+"/all")
      .then(res=>setPoemData(res.data))
      .catch((err) => {
        if (err.response) {
          console.log(err.response.data)
          console.log(err.response.status)
          console.log(err.response.headers)
        } else if (err.request) {
          console.log(err.request)
        } else {
          console.log('Error', err.message)
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

The results get put into a div that generates a card using my viewer component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is called on non-array variables, it will throws error.

Since the page breaks after a bad API call, one way to prevent it is to check if `poem` is an Array using [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) before performing `poem.map()`.

```
const Viewer = ({ poem }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {Array.isArray(poem) // Add extra type checking before rendering
        ? (
          poem.map((item) => {
            let author = item.author;
            let title = item.title;
            let lines = item.lines;
            if (author != undefined && title != undefined) {
              return (
                <>
                  <div className="viewer">
                    <div className="author">{author}</div>
                    <div className="title">{title}</div>
                    <div className="lines">
                      {lines.map((line) => (
                        <div>{line}</div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </>
              );
            }
          })
        )
        : null // or a error message component
      }
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try log the variable poem within the component.

If an API returns nothing, the variable poem will not exist in this context, and therefore neither will poem.map.

Have a look into conditional rendering - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

You could handle this in the rendering function with something similar to the below.

```
poem && Viewer(poem)
```